# Normal vector of a separating or supporting hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I would like to ask how to find a normal vector $\gamma$ for a separating or supporting hyperplane for the following sets $A$ and points $d$:

$1.\quad A=\{(x,y):x\ge 0,y \ge 0\}$ and $d=(-1,-1)$

$2.\quad A=\{(x,y,z):x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\le 9\}$ and $d=(3,0,0)$

Hint is to draw a picture, but I still don't understand how I know according to the picture that the answer is:

$1.\quad \gamma=(-1,-1)$  or  $\gamma=(1,1)$

$2.\quad \gamma=(1,0,0)$  or  $\gamma=(-1,0,0)$

Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: In the first case, the hyperplane is a line with slope $-1$.  In the second case, the hyperplane is a plane perpendicular to the $x$ axis.  The normal vector is a vector perpendicular to the hyperplane.  All hyperplanes can be defined using a normal vector, and a signed distance from origin; if the hyperplane is in the same direction as the normal vector, then the signed distance is positive, negative if in the opposite direction, and zero if the hyperplane passes through origin.

Comment: I don't understand. How we know from the picture if the hyperplane and normal vector has the same direction or not?  If you talk about the distance why is the normal vector (1,0,0) in the second case and not (3,0,0), because the distance of the x axis is 3 not 1.

Comment: The hyperplane is defined by the normal vector, and signed distance from origin.  The vector and the hyperplane are *perpendicular*.  The magnitude of the normal vector is irrelevant (it only defines the length units for the signed distance).  In this question, the signed distance is ignored, so you can place the hyperplane anywhere you deem fit.  The question only asks about its orientation (and not exact location).

Comment: What about the set $A=\{(x,y): x^{2}+y^{2} < 10\}$ and the point $(3,1)$. What is the normal vector in this case?

Comment: The set $A$ is a circular disk of radius $\sqrt{10}$ centered at origin, not including the perimeter. The distance from the point to origin is $\sqrt{3^2 + 1} = \sqrt{10}$, so it is on the perimeter of the disk, and there is no gap between them.  Assuming your definition of separating hyperplanes allows the no-gap case (it varies!), the normal for both the separating and the supporting hyperplanes are $(3\lambda, \lambda)$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda \ne 0$; in your notation, either $(3, 1)$ or $(-3, -1)$.